# Magento Image upload using import / export does not work. It upload all the information except images

Tags: php, magento, csv, import, magento-1.7

I have created one product and i want to copy the same product and information for another products where only title will be changed slightly but its picture and other details remains same

So i have downloaded my product that i have created and using CSV file format , i have uploaded it to Magento backend , It worked and sucessfully uploaded the file as i copied all the data from export file

However even though i have given the same image path that is generated by export file , it did not copy the image , All other products are online but without any image!

/k/i/test.jpg

Above is the path that magento gave me when i exported the original product , however it wont work when i upload it again

anyone can solve this mystery ?

Answer (score 3):

For importing the images, follow this steps

1) All the images should be kept in (your store directory)/media/import , if 'import' directory does not exist, create one.

2) Suppose your images is named 'test.jpg', so copy that image in /media/import, and write the path like '/test.jpg' in the CSV used for importing, don't forget the forward slash.

3) If you want you can create directory inside 'import', suppose you created a directory 'catalog', so the path will be '/catalog/test.jpg' in your CSV import file

4) If you have successfully imported the images, remove the name from CSV for subsequent importing, else duplicate images will be there for products.

Comment: thank you for your such fast and accurate answer . It has started working now and imported one image However , i have keep two image files in the import folder and i created 10 products out of that same image , Now will it create a duplicate images on my server ? Or it will use the same image for all 10 products ?

As you have mentioned this in number 4 to avoid duplicate images , Please can you guide on that topic ?

Also I have given two images in my CSV file , however it has only imported one image in the product , Please can you help in that well , what i have done wrong in my CSV ?
Thanks

Comment: I do not want to create a multiple image on my server for the same product , your help be much appreciated

Comment: Hey, so if you want only one image, Just delete the products and redo the import. You will have to if you run the import twice.

Comment: @sh- if i can explain again , We have the same item description and item image , for many products , Now i want to upload all this products using CSV , so if i keep the same image name in the CSV upload file , will it create a multiple image files in the backend ? or it will only create one image ? As magento is using same image for all 10 products ?

Comment: I think it should only create one per import.

Comment: As i guess there must be a way to find out that it is using the same image or creating a separate copy @SH-

Comment: You can look in the folder it is copied to.

Comment: Please can you tell me the path where it copy the image after processing file ? @sh-

Comment: It does make duplicates. For example, if you had an image called "test.jpg" and uploaded 10 products with the same image, the images would be copied to the folder "/media/catalog/product/t/e/" under the names "test.jpg", "test_1.jpg", "test_2.jpg", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for us:

1. Make sure that the following directories (and their sub-directories) within the Magento install directory are writable: var and media
2. Make sure that you have the gd libraries installed (sudo apt-get install php5-gd
   on ubuntu)
3. Make sure your images are named correctly in the CSV file. See here: http://blog.mag-manager.com/2013/01/101-magento-import-questions.html
4. Test that you can edit a product and upload images first. That is how we figured out that the upload was not a problem by itself!